# How to set server/build environment variables in gatsby-config.js file with Github secrets

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, gatsby

I'm using Firebase hosting for my Gatsby application. I use the plugin gatsby-firesource. You need to put in the firebase credentials in the options of the plugin. I use environment variables for that.When running locally all works fine. No problem building the application.

I set up an CI/CD workflow with Github actions and secrets. But I don't get it to work. The environment variables are returned `undefined` I've read the Gatsby documentation about setting the environment variables. I don't understand it fully. The environment variables are only necessary during the build stage. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

My gatsby-config.js file (short version):

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${activeEnv}`,
});

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'testsite',
    siteUrl: 'testsite.co',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-firesource',
      options: {
        credential: {
          type: process.env.FIREBASE_TYPE,
          project_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          private_key_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
          private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
          client_email: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
          client_id: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID,
          auth_uri: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_URI,
          token_uri: process.env.FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI,
          auth_provider_x509_cert_url:
            process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL,
          client_x509_cert_url: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL,
        },
        types: [
          {
            type: 'Sound',
            collection: 'sounds',
            map: (doc) => ({
              title: doc.title,
              mp3: doc.mp3,
              WAV: doc.WAV,
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

My Github actions yaml file:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      CI: true
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          touch .env.production
          echo FIREBASE_TYPE: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TYPE }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_AUTH_URI: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_AUTH_URI }} >> .env
          echo FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI }} >> .env
          cat .env.production
          rm .gitignore
          git config user.email "test@testsite.com"
          git config user.name "test"
          git add .
          git commit -m "environment variables"
          npm ci && npm run test && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TESTSITE }}'
          projectId: TESTSITE
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```

Answer (score 1):

> The environment variables are only necessary during the build stage

Well, that's not exactly right. Gatsby needs environment variables as well as in the `gatsby develop` and in the  `gatsby build` process. By default, it will take the `.env.development` and `.env.production` files respectively. In other words, they are needed in each compilation.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) (and the workaround applies in all CI/CD ecosystems like Netlify), it seems that you need to add the variables in the GitHub dashboard:

[image]

Once created, they will be available in your GitHub actions:

```
steps:
  - name: Hello world action
    with: # Set the secret as an input
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    env: # Or as an environment variable
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
```

If the approach doesn't work, try prefixing the environment variables with `GATSBY_`, in Netlify it's a mandatory configuration to make the variables available in the server-side, so, without knowing how GitHub actions work, if the previous approach doesn't work, you can try it in the GitHub environment, as the [docs suggest](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#example-of-using-an-environment-variable):

> In Node, your site has access to your `API_KEY` (Server-side) using the
> identifier `process.env.API_KEY`. To access it client-side, you can use
> a `.env.*` file containing `API_KEY`. However, you are **strongly** advised
> against checking these files into source control as it’s a security
> issue to expose the API key. As a more secure alternative, you can
> prefix your variable with `GATSBY_` (as shown above). With this prefix,
> Gatsby automatically embeds the variable as `process.env.GATSBY\_\*` in
> compiled JS making it available in the browser context without
> exposing it elsewhere.

So, following the previous example, `EXAMPLE_API_KEY` will become `GATSBY_EXAMPLE_API_KEY`.

Comment: Thanks Ferran, I will try it. Small question, I understand that using the prefix GATSBY_ will make the environment variables available in the browser context. Isn't it then possible for a user to get access to the secrets?

Comment: Only in your code, external users won't have access

Comment: Hi Ferran, it finally worked. I did a couple of stupid things. ```touch .env.production``` and then echo it into ```.env``` use ```:``` instead of ```=``` when setting the environment  variables. Big SIGH. Thanks again for your answer but I used a different workflow and no plugin just the firebase nmp library.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that I copied the keys not into right file. `.env` instead of `.env.production`. I also did `echo FIREBASE_TYPE: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TYPE }} >> .env` instead of `echo FIREBASE_TYPE=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TYPE }} >> .env` (`=` NOT `:`).

I don't use the gatsby-firesource plugin anymore but I use the firebase npm library. So I don't know if the new setup also works for the gatsby-firesource plugin. I think it will.

This setup worked finally (the yaml file):

```
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      CI: true
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          touch .env.development
          echo GATSBY_API_KEY=${{ secrets.GATSBY_API_KEY }} >> .env.development
          echo GATSBY_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.GATSBY_AUTH_DOMAIN }} >> .env.development
          echo GATSBY_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.GATSBY_PROJECT_ID }} >> .env.development
          echo GATSBY_STORAGE_BUCKET=${{ secrets.GATSBY_STORAGE_BUCKET }} >> .env.development
          echo GATSBY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=${{ secrets.GATSBY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID}} >> .env.development
          echo GATSBY_APP_ID=${{ secrets.GATSBY_APP_ID }} >> .env.development
          echo GATSBY_MEASUREMENT_ID=${{ secrets.GATSBY_MEASUREMENT_ID}} >> .env.development
          cat .env.development
          rm .gitignore
          git config user.email "youremail@test.com"
          git config user.name "username"
          git add .
          git commit -m "environment variables"
          npm ci && npm run test && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SOUNDSFROMTHEWEB }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: soundsfromtheweb
        env:
          FIREBASE_CLI_PREVIEWS: hostingchannels
```